# Flutter Google Direction API "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key."

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am testing the Google Directions API on the Flutter Android app.
I have created a Google Maps API key as follows:
[image: 1.png]

[image: 2.png]

And I have called BASE_URL
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=35.098480364448235,-109.62431179538783&destination=35.21340949112603,-113.15068285745188&key=Google_api_key

---

result  is :
[image: 3. png.]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You can try to change application restrictions from Android Apps to none. I know, it is nonsense but I fixed the same issue this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But why it is not working when I select Android app?
Will it work  on both  android and iOS?

Comment: It will work on both Android and iOS. But you can define another key for iOS, and use it on iOS too.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to be an acceptable answer in here for the next visitors, the application restrictions field does not work as expected. Changing it from `Android Apps` to `None` fixed the issue.